# Can't determine the biggest complexity

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, graph-algorithm

I have a program where one element of the code has the complexity O(|V| * (|V| + |E|)) (where V are the vertices in my graph, and E are the edges), and another part of my code has the complexity O(n log n). What I can't seem to figure out is what the total complexity of my program will be? Is O(n log n) bigger than O(|V| * (|V| + |E|))?

Comment: Is there a connection between n and the values of |V| or |E|? In some cases, the letter n denotes |V|, but I'm not sure if that's also the case here.

Comment: Yeah, I think it does. The part that is n log n is where I use Collections.sort, and the list that I sort is |V| long (all the vertices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of graph algorithms, we typically denote |V| by n and |E| by m. Therefore, your algorithm has two parts, one taking time O(n(n + m)) and one taking time O(n log n). The first part can be simplified down to O(n<sup>2</sup> + nm). The total runtime is therefore O(n<sup>2</sup> + nm + n log n). Since n log n = o(n<sup>2</sup>), this in turn simplifies down to O(n<sup>2</sup> + nm), which gives your overall runtime.

If you're assuming that the graph is connected, then you can further simplify this down O(nm) because you know that m is at least n - 1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! So n log n is the same as n^2? I didn't know this, thank you :)

Comment: n log n is **not** the same as n^2. The notation "n log n = o(n^2)" means "n log n grows strictly asymptotically slower than the function n^2." As a result, you can drop the n log n term, since it's dominated by the n^2 term.

Comment: You can justify dropping the n lg n term without using little-oh. Even for some function g(n) that is the asymptotically the same as n^2, `O(n^2 + g(n)) = O(2n^2) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: @chepner That's true. I wanted to highlight specifically that n log n grows strictly slower than n^2, so I chose to use little-o notation.